# Headphones phones don't work on my Toshiba Satellite L655d-S5066 laptop

Tags: 10.10, sound

I'm using a toshiba satellite L655d-S5066 my headphones don't work is there a way to fix them using ubuntu or is this a sacrifice to use ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at this link and then edit your question adding more detail? http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 2):

I found this fix and it worked on the Toshiba Satellite L655D-S5066
Easiest way:

Open a terminal.

Type:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Press enter and it will ask for your password.

In gedit, add:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=ideapad
```

to the bottom of the file and save it. Be very careful not to change anything else, this instance of gedit is running with superuser permissions and you could damage your installation.

You’ll need to reboot for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe external speakers are disabled by default. Open up terminal and enter

`sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer`

Then enable headphones/external speakers.

Comment: the headphones/external speaker on/off thing does not appear only maste,pcm,beep and 3 microphones

Comment: Easiest way:

Open a terminal.

Type:

gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Press enter and it will ask for your password.

In gedit, add:

options snd-hda-intel model=ideapad

to the bottom of the file and save it. Be very careful not to change anything else, this instance of gedit is running with superuser permissions and you could damage your installation.

You’ll need to reboot for the changes to take effect.