# No sound for headphones

Tags: 11.04, sound, headphones

I was trying some of the solutions published in this forum for the same problem, but just one in particular work for me: add the line of code in the file alsa-base.conf. This just works for a few days, now the problem is back again.

Any solution to fix this problem for good?

---

Compaq Presario CQ40

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
01:05.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc RS780 Azalia controller
```

Comment: Can you please add links to the answers you already tried out?

Comment: What I have tried this time in addition to what worked for me a few days is to create a sound.conf file in the same directory of alsa-base.conf, I also set the alsamixer without success. 

But in the past I've tried to update alsa drivers without being able to solve the problem.

__--
http://askubuntu.com/questions/32956/headphones-phones-dont-work-on-my-toshiba-satellite-l655d-s5066-laptop

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but I have solution, not a  very good one, but the only one that works for me (DELL Vostro 3750) Ubuntu 11.04. When I boot in Ubuntu and I do not have sound in headphones I press Power button and hold it until laptop turns off (Forced Power Off). Then when I boot back in Ubuntu there is sound in headphones and stays that way until I do normal reboot.

P.S. In 11.10 this problem is fixed.